# Embed iOS UIViewController in a Flutter widget

Tags: ios, flutter, uiviewcontroller, flutter-platform-channel

I have a Flutter fullscreen modal widget with a header, a footer and some content which should be rendered natively for iOS. I know I can host iOS `UIView`s in Flutter using Platform Views and I managed to do all the logic to get this working.

My issue is that I need to host a whole view controller within this widget, not only a simple view, and this view controller belongs to a third-party framework.

An option would be implementing the header and footer natively, but this would take a lot of time since this would involve passing lot of data, performing network requests, adding callbacks and so on. I read online that a `UIKitViewController` exists, but it can only be created from [`PlatformViewServices`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/services/PlatformViewsService/initUiKitView.html), which is still a work in progress and should not be used. I didn't manage to find proper documentation online.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can try this.

```
class NativeView: NSObject, FlutterPlatformView {
    private var _vc: UIViewController

    init(
      frame: CGRect,
      viewIdentifier viewId: Int64,
      arguments args: Any?,
      binaryMessenger messenger: FlutterBinaryMessenger?
    ) {
      _vc = UIViewController()
      
      super.init()
    }

    func view() -> UIView {
      return _vc.view
    }
}
```

Calling `_vc.view` will call `loadView()` and `viewDidLoad()` when view is not initialized yet.